# Mitigate CSRF attacks in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, csrf, xss

**tl;dr**

I want to pick your collective brains for my psuedo logic for preventing both XSS and CSRF attacks at the same time when dealing with authenticated sessions in SPA frontends like React (but this applies to any modern frontend pattern where most or all data used in the frontend is populated through incremental XMLHttpRequests that pass API responses to JavaScript logic rather than relying on server side rendering of HTML/backend redirects for the majority of a website).
The reason why I am rehashing this after observing an abundance of answers online is because all the search results on the subject I have encountered suffer one or both of the following problems:

1. Articles target the aforementioned SSR way of doing things like injecting a CSRF Token as a hidden input in an HTML form
2. Articles with solutions that only mitigate XSS attacks or CSRF attacks, but not at the same time
   I believe there are some pure React/Express based node modules which may or may not solve these problems. But I want to understand a solution at a technical level to be able to implement this in a React SPA + Go backend setup, or any other backend that isn't Node based. I am also making the post because of the lack of public forum to point out security flaws in other approaches I have seen.

**tl;dr end**

---

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M6N7gEZ-IUQ) argues about why this is might be a non-issue, but is also the starting point of how I thought about the problem.

The problem boils down to the following: an XSS vulnerability is quite trivial to fix by utilizing a [HttpOnly cookie](https://owasp.org/www-community/HttpOnly) inside a modern frontend framework. But [this approach alone is still vulnerable to CSRF attacks](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/175536/does-a-csrf-cookie-need-to-be-httponly).

The traditional approach to mitigate CSRF attacks via inserting a hidden input field into server side rendered HTML does not apply to modern SPA's.

---

The approach I think would prevent both XSS and CSRF is by combining both:

1. Modern frontend framework + HttpOnly cookie to prevent XSS
2. CSRF Token passed in every XMLHttpRequest to protected endpoints as a header.

I partially base my logic on [this article](https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/react-csrf-protection-guide-examples-and-how-to-enable-it/), but since this project isn't on Github or Medium, I can't find any criticisms of potential security flaws, or anyone praising it as sound.

Here is the detailed approach on how I think you could mitigate XSS and CSRF attacks:

1. A React rendered login page (/login) you log into via true HTML form submit (not via XMLHttpRequest inside a button onsubmit with a `e.preventDefault()`), causing the backend to write a JWT httponly cookie, and redirects back to the root (/), and a re-render of the entire SPA DOM with the cookie now stored in the browser.
2. Frontend needs to request protected data from backend via `fetch`/`axios`.
3. Before sending that request for data, frontend requests the CSRF token from the backend which is validated via JWT httponly cookie.
4. The actual request to the protected resource is made with both the httponly JWT cookie AND the CSRF Token sent as a header.

Potential flaws to this logic: Because retrieving the CSRF Token only requires the httponly JWT cookie to validate the session, this is potentially the weak link in protecting all calls. However, because the CSRF token is never stored, it adds an extra layer of security.

---

### Alternative approaches:

1. Store CSRF Token in localStorage. I'm not sure, but I have a bad feeling about this approach since you can just do `localStorage.getItem('csrf_token_name')` in the browser console to retrieve the CSRF token.
2. Store CSRF token in JavaScript location. In React terms, either use a `CSRFContext` (via `createContext()`), or if you are a masochist, Redux. This approach is cleaner than retrieving the CSRF token before every protected API call. Also, although this is probably more hidden than `localStorage`, due to production minifying JavaScript logic as well as other pseudo-protection patterns that are afforded to modern compiled frontend code, you probably want to minimize storing anything in JavaScript if possible.

With both of these alternative solutions, you are still stuck with the problem of needing to retrieve the CSRF token from the backend via cookie session validation alone.

Comment: How do you stop an XSS attack from just calling your safe `fetch` functions and bypassing your entire strategy?

Comment: After all, XSS and CSRF are entirely different attacks with different mitigation strategies. Using any modern framework (like React) should prevent all XSS attacks. The moment you do have a XSS vulnerability, the attacker can execute arbitrary code, and is indistinguishable from the rest of the Javascript on your website.

Comment: Can you elaborate, what's the difference between the normal frontend performing step 2-4 and an attacker exploiting a XSS vulnerability performing step 2-4? To me it seems, that an attacker could still perform these steps and thus obtain protected data. If no, why not?

Comment: Regarding "XSS can be mitigated by using httponly cookie sessions because this type of cookie cannot be accessed through client side script": where can you find this information in the provided OWASP link? As far as I've seen it does not mention this, at least directly

Comment: @A_A Sorry, wrong link: owasp.org/www-community/HttpOnly It seems like this is extra protection against a potential XSS vulnerability that is already mitigated by using a modern frontend framework.

Comment: Looking into it, I using httpOnly cookies mitigates the ability for third party to swipe the cookie and send it elsewhere to be used maliciously using JavaScript's document.cookie, but as @Stefnotch points out, it does not prevent a safe fetch function within the scope of the said application

Comment: "How do you stop an XSS attack from just calling your safe fetch functions and bypassing your entire strategy?" Would the user input escaping that occurs in modern frontends prevent this entirely?

I adjusted the question to focus on CSRF

Comment: Frameworks like React should properly differ between user data and html. For instance `<div>{user.name}</div>` is handled such that a username `<script>alert(1)</script>` will be inserted as text and not as html. This makes it harder for developers to write vulnerable code that accidentally interprets user data as html/code, and thus prevents XSS. In case you want to know more about XSS, you could check the [portswigger documentation](https://portswigger.net/web-security/cross-site-scripting) on it @GilgameshSkytrooper

Comment: @GilgameshSkytrooper Modern frameworks DO NOT escape user input in general. It's incidental that some kinds of user input don't cause arbitrary code to be executed, it's not because a framework is fool-proof. Consider updating the question, CSRF and XSS are just different kinds of threats in this context, XSS seems to be irrelevant. The LS argument is common and misleading. If a culprit is able to execute arbitrary code in a browser and call localStorage.getItem, a user is in deep trouble already